# Terraform and docker provider (push image to docker hub)

Tags: docker, terraform

Good afternoon.
Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to put a built image from a Dockerfile into docker hub. However, I get an error or authentication if I change the address in the registry_auth block or that I make an error in the block
I have a main.tf file

```
`terraform {
  required_providers {
    docker = {
      source  = "kreuzwerker/docker"
      version = "3.0.2"
    }
  }
}
provider "docker" {
  registry_auth {
    address = "registry-1.docker.io/v1" <- here I tried different addresses, please help me fill in the correct value for     docker hub
    username = "my_email"
    password = "my_strong+passwd"
  }
}
resource "docker_image" "application" {
  name  = "application"
  build {
      context = "./Dockerfile"
      dockerfile = "Dockerfile"
  }
  keep_locally = false
}
resource "docker_registry_image" "application" {
  name = "docker_image.application.name"
}`
```

Please help me fix my code, there are a lot of examples for aws on the Internet, but I don’t use it, there’s simply no need, the standard docker hub is enough.
Thanks a lot for any help

I worked with two blocks
`resource "docker_registry_image" "skench" { name = "docker_image.application.name" }`

I tried to specify a variety of values instead of skench (this is my nickname on docker hub), which I thought were correct, but I did it based on examples on the Internet for aws.

Comment: Why are you trying to use Terraform for this? Terraform is great for managing stateful infrastructure but I don't see an upside to using a special Terraform provider for managing container images.

Comment: In `docker_registry_image.application`, you're quoting the `name`; is it trying to push an image named `docker_image.application.name` (not a valid Docker image name), instead of pushing the value of the `name` property from `docker_image.application`?

Comment: Hi, please try to use `registry-1.docker.io` as an address. And it is better to use Personal Access Token instead of using plain password.